# Propensity score estimation with no decision point

Tags: regression, causality, propensity-scores, matching

Let's say I have a treated group and a non-treated group, but there was never an explicit decision to join either group. The groups have ended up this way through a long chain of events. The two groups also differ on a number of observable characteristics. What are people's thoughts on performing propensity score methods as a means to facilitate balance/reduce model dependence with data like this? My specific use of propensity scores will be to estimate a treatment effect, so I would like to either use propensity score methods or matching methods to reduce dependence on my final model which will attempt to estimate the treatment effect.

Comment: It may depend on the causal model you are considering. If you mean using the PS as a covariate for the estimation of the treatment effect, I would avoid it since it doesn't take into account of unseen sources of bias. I would go for other confounding correction methods such as backdoor criterion.

Comment: Can you explain more about the treatment? It's unclear how your situation differs from other observational studies where treatment is not assigned by the researcher.